# BizTalk file Archive

Tags: biztalk, archive

I have an business requirement where each input file received on FTPS adapter at input location in BizTalk want to send back to client in original format at Archive location (FTPS).

Each input port have inbound map so original message converted and submitted to message box and when I read message on send port its already converted.

How do I get original message and send back to client.

Comment: Do you have to send it back to the same FTP server you got it from, or is the client FTP server at a different address?

Answer (score 0):

Here as some options to look at

- By using a File Archiving Pipeline component as the first thing in the pipeline and writing it to a folder and then having BizTalk pick it up from there using a pass-thru to send it on again.
- Have a send port that also subscribed to the converted message that maps it back to the original message and sends it back. This will only be possible if you the original mapping is loss-less (don't lose any information).
- Some of the FTP type adapters have the option to move the file after it is transferred rather than just deleting it, if it has use that.